# need help on simple Java pattern coding

Tags: java, for-loop

I am to make this following pattern on a for loop:

```
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXY
XXXXXXXXYY
XXXXXXXYYY
...
```

..and so on

```
public class ex{
    public static void main(String[] args){
            for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
                    System.out.println();
                    for(int j=0;j<=10;j++){
                            if(i==0){
                                    System.out.print("X");
                            }

                            if(i==1){
                                    System.out.print("X");
                                    if(j==9){
                                            System.out.print("Y");
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

}
~

I am getting extra "X" at the end for my output that I don't want.
I think there is a better way to do this but can't think of a way right now

Any help guys?

Comment: Is this homework? It will characterize the response.

Comment: its a problem from a book im reading for myself just got stuck XD

Comment: Hint: inside the outer loop create two nested loops next two each other. First prints ... and the second prints ... - fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try nesting two loops inside one loop. Count up to `i` and then continue counting up to `10` on each iteration of the outer loop:

```
// 10 lines
for(int i = 10; i >= 0; i--){

    int j = 0; 

    // Print 'X's (10 - i of them)
    for(; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print("X");

    // Print 'Y's (i of them)
    for(; j < 10; j++)
        System.out.print("Y");

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: thank you. i just tried this out and it worked. the comment helped me out as i read the code out loud. thanks!

Comment: @Jay You're very welcome! Let me know if you don't understand any parts of it. Also have you learnt about constants yet. You may benefit from putting `10` into a constant since it is used in two places. Generally when programming you don't want to repeat yourself because if you need to make changes you have to edit multiple parts of the program. It would get crazy in a huge piece of software. If you declare a constant for the 10 and use it in both places then you  only need to make one edit to change the length of the output.

Answer (score 0):

hint: each row is of the same length, there is just one less X and one more Y on each row down.

```
public class XY
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                System.out.print(xy(10,10));
        }
        public static String xy(int rows,int origRows)
        {
                return X(rows,origRows-rows)+"\n"+((rows>0)?xy(rows-1,origRows):"");
        }
        public static String X(int x,int y)
        {
                return (x>0?"X":"")+((x>0||y>0)?X(x-1,y-1):"")+(y>0?"Y":"");
        }
}
```

teehee.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your specific question is:

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
```

`i<=10` should be `i<10`, since from 0 to 10 (inclusive) there are eleven loops.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient version, but here it goes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(repeat("X", 10 - i) + repeat("Y", i));
    }
}

private static String repeat(String string, int times) {
    return new String(new char[times]).replaceAll("\0", string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition for the / diagonal of a matrix is i + j = n, so the left-upper part is i + j < n and i + j > n for the right-lower part.

```
public static void main(String... arg) {
    int n = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if ( i + j < n) {
                System.out.print("X");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Y");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

If you want to separate on \ diagonal, the condition for the diagonal is i = j, for the upper part i > j and for the lower part i < j.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
 public class ex {
    public static final String X = "X";
    public static final String Y = "Y";

    public static void main(String[] args){
      printall(10, 0);
    }

    private static void printall(int length, int saturation){
      if (saturation > length) {
        return;
      } else {
        System.out.print(printRow(length, saturation, 0);
        printall(length, saturation + 1);
      }
    }

    private static String printrow(int length, int saturation, int position) {
      if (position > length) {
        return "";
      } else {
        return getChar(length, saturation, position) + printrow(length, saturation, position + 1);
      }
    }

    private static String getChar(int length, int saturation, int position) {
      if (length-saturation < position) {
        return Y;
      } else {
        return X;
      }
    }
  }
```