# Printing out series of numbers in java

Tags: java, for-loop

hi guys i am just doing some reading for myself to learn java and came across this problem and is currently stuck.

i need to print out series of number based on the input given by the user.
for example, if input = 5, the output should be as follows

@1@22@333@4444@55555

```
    import java.util.*;

public class ex5{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please type a #: ");

                int input = kb.nextInt();

                for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
                        if(input==1){
                                System.out.print("@1");
                        }
                        if(input==2){
                                System.out.print("@1@22");
                        }
                }

        }
}
```

this doesnt seem to be working because this is the output i get

Please type a #:
2
@1@22@1@22

im not sure what to put inside the for loop right now and i dont think i am using the for loop here very well either...

any help guys?

Comment: You asked a similar question some time back! What gives?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922715/need-help-on-simple-java-pattern-coding

Comment: still on the same chapter. lol i thought it was different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        System.out.print("@");
        for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) System.out.print(i);
    }
```

out

```
@1@22@333@4444@55555
```

Answer (score 2):

you're going to need a nested for-loop to solve this problem.

Comment: +1 for hint rather than solution. Learning the basics is best done through understanding the logic rather than being handed the solution outright.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this isn't how you want to do it. You're going to want to build the string inside the for loop.

Start with a new string

`String s = "";`

As you loop, add to that string.

```
for(int i=1;i<=input;i++){
     s += @;
     for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
         s+=i;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` instead of excessive string concatenation.

Comment: I thought this basic problem warranted a basic solution. Although I agree StringBuilder is better, I think in terms of understanding the problem, this method suffices.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The exercise places emphasis on string construction..using "low level" string concatenation instead of using a `StringBuilder` is reenforcing bad programming practices, especially as `n` strings increases.

Comment: While StringBuilder does offer better performance when used in a loop, I would say that the emphasis on this particular exercise - clearly a "programming beginners" exercise - is more to understand basic loops and loop logic. This is a "week one: learn Java" exercise and expecting a beginner to know the API and optimise for performance is a high expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a nested `for` loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type a #: ");

    int input = kb.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
        System.out.print("@");
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are checking for the numbers 1 and 2 in the if statement.  It is hard coded to only check for these two numbers and would not work once you go past the values that you have an if statement for

What you want to do is to output the value of your iterator (in your case, i) i times (hint, you can use another loop inside the big loop) and then ad an @ sign at the end of the string.

I will try to not give you any code so you can learn it yourself, but feel free to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print given number - given number of times?
Then you'll need two loops for this - outer loop for iterating the number and inner - for iterating -times the given number.

It would be something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < input; ++i) {
    System.out.print("@");
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```